# libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found | Glxgears error, Docker, CUDA, VirtualGL

Tags: ubuntu, docker, opengl, cuda

when I run **glxgears**, I get following error.

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Error: couldn't get an RGB, Double-buffered visual
```

My system is ubuntu 16.04 as docker image - `nvidia/cuda:8.0-runtime-ubuntu16.04`.

The image contains VirtualGL and TurboVNC and its is started with the following parameters:

`docker run --runtime=nvidia --privileged -d -v /tmp/.X11-unix/X0:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 -e USE_DISPLAY="7" my_image`

There is no problem if I change the base image to `nvidia/cuda:10.2-runtime-ubuntu18.04`. But an application for which this container is, needs CUDA 8.

I found some advice to remove library: `sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1`. But it does not work.

**Ubuntu 16.04, CUDA 8:**

```
user@host:/opt/noVNC$ sudo ldconfig -p | grep -i libGL.so
    libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1
    libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
    libGL.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
user@host:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ll libGL*
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      13 Jun 14  2018 libGL.so -> mesa/libGL.so
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      32 May 25 14:14 libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1 -> libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.440.33.01
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   63696 Nov 12  2019 libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.440.33.01
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      29 May 25 14:14 libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2 -> libGLESv2_nvidia.so.440.33.01
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  111416 Nov 12  2019 libGLESv2_nvidia.so.440.33.01
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  911218 Oct 23  2015 libGLU.a
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Oct 23  2015 libGLU.so -> libGLU.so.1.3.1
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 Oct 23  2015 libGLU.so.1 -> libGLU.so.1.3.1
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  453352 Oct 23  2015 libGLU.so.1.3.1
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      26 May 25 14:14 libGLX_indirect.so.0 -> libGLX_nvidia.so.440.33.01
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      26 May 25 14:14 libGLX_nvidia.so.0 -> libGLX_nvidia.so.440.33.01
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1114496 Nov 12  2019 libGLX_nvidia.so.440.33.01
user@host:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ll mesa
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root     31 Jun 14  2018 ld.so.conf
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 Jun 14  2018 libGL.so -> libGL.so.1.2.0
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 Jun 14  2018 libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.2.0
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 471680 Jun 14  2018 libGL.so.1.2.0
```

**Ubuntu 18.04, CUDA 10:**

```
user@host:/opt/noVNC$ sudo ldconfig -p | grep -i libGL.so
    libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
user@host:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ll libGL*
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      14 May 10  2019 libGL.so.1 -> libGL.so.1.0.0
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  567624 May 10  2019 libGL.so.1.0.0
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      32 May 20 16:43 libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.1 -> libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.440.33.01
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   63696 Nov 12  2019 libGLESv1_CM_nvidia.so.440.33.01
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      29 May 20 16:43 libGLESv2_nvidia.so.2 -> libGLESv2_nvidia.so.440.33.01
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  111416 Nov 12  2019 libGLESv2_nvidia.so.440.33.01
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 May 21  2016 libGLU.so.1 -> libGLU.so.1.3.1
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  453352 May 21  2016 libGLU.so.1.3.1
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15 May 10  2019 libGLX.so.0 -> libGLX.so.0.0.0
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   68144 May 10  2019 libGLX.so.0.0.0
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Feb 19 05:09 libGLX_indirect.so.0 -> libGLX_mesa.so.0
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      20 Feb 19 05:09 libGLX_mesa.so.0 -> libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  488344 Feb 19 05:09 libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      26 May 20 16:43 libGLX_nvidia.so.0 -> libGLX_nvidia.so.440.33.01
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1114496 Nov 12  2019 libGLX_nvidia.so.440.33.01
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      22 May 10  2019 libGLdispatch.so.0 -> libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0
    -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  612792 May 10  2019 libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0
user@host:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ll mesa
    ls: cannot access 'mesa': No such file or directory
```

The host has CUDA 10.2 but I do not know if it is required and can cause a problem.

I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 15):

The two errors also appear when [Running ROS with GUI in Docker using Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2)](http://marinerobotics.gtorg.gatech.edu/running-ros-with-gui-in-docker-using-windows-subsystem-for-linux-2-wsl2/).

The error `libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found` can be fixed with:

[`export LIBGL_ALWAYS_INDIRECT=1`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127011/win10-linux-subsystem-libgl-error-no-matching-fbconfigs-or-visuals-found-libgl)

The error `libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast` can be fixed with:

[`sudo apt-get install -y mesa-utils libgl1-mesa-glx`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40092796/libgl-error-failed-to-load-driver-swrast-running-ubuntu-docker-container-on)

---

Probably irrelevant side-note:

For "the ROS with GUI on Docker guide" to run, you also have to install dbus.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y dbus
```

I do not think this is relevant here, since you will see the two errors in question only after having installed dbus, but I do not know the background of the question, perhaps it helps. Installing dbus would get rid of the error [D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; failed to read machine uuid: Failed to open “/var/lib/dbus/machine-id”](http://www.torkwrench.com/2011/12/16/d-bus-library-appears-to-be-incorrectly-set-up-failed-to-read-machine-uuid-failed-to-open-varlibdbusmachine-id/).

Comment: Would like to give +2.  You solved two of the three problems I have, getting OpenGL work from Docker, in an unrelated project.

Comment: I logged in just to give you a an upvote

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to replace `nvidia/cuda:8.0-runtime-ubuntu16.04` image with `nvidia/opengl:1.0-glvnd-runtime-ubuntu16.04` and install CUDA 8 manually.

CUDA 8 installation:
https://gitlab.com/nvidia/container-images/cuda/-/blob/ubuntu16.04/8.0/runtime/Dockerfile

Do not forget to add `display` to nvidia capabilities var:

```
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES compute,utility,display
```

https://hub.docker.com/r/nvidia/opengl

Answer (score 0):

I had similar errors on a docker container(Ubuntu 18) on host(Ubuntu 22) with Nvidia.
Here is what I did:

Step 1 (On the **host** machine):
#Install nvidia-container-toolkit

```
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | apt-key add -
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/ubuntu22.04/nvidia-docker.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
apt update
apt -y install nvidia-container-toolkit
systemctl restart docker
```

#Test

```
docker run --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.5.2-base-ubuntu20.04 nvidia-smi
```

#If you find issues with the test, restart your host machine.

Step 2 (Running docker)
#Run with flags NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all -e NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all  --gpus all

#In my case:

```
docker run -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all -e NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all  --gpus all -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY myimage
```

Step 3 (If you are using vscode devcontainer)

#Provide the following in the runargs in devcontainer.json :

```
"runArgs": [
    "-e","DISPLAY=:1",
    "-e","NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=all",
    "-e","NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES=all",
    "--gpus","all",
    "--runtime=nvidia",
]
```

#In the mounts section of decontainer.json:

```
"mounts": [
    "source=/tmp/.X11-unix,target=/tmp/.X11-unix,type=bind",
],
```

Comment: Sometimes you may also be need to mount dbus on the container, then mount it with volume mount "source=/var/run/dbus,target=/var/run/dbus,type=bind"